# android 8.0 portrait mode app some time showing landscape screen

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-8.0-oreo, landscape-portrait, portrait

My android app have 2 portrait mode activities.

```
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
```

There is a button in my MainActivity. And button click opens my second activity.

```
intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

I turned on auto rotation in my emulator and using emulator in **landscape mode**. Then open application and click on button to open second activity.But some time its shows second activity screen in landscape mode(fraction of seconds only). It only happens in Android 8.0 emulators.

Is this issue due to my code or android 8.0?

**More Info:**

targetSdkVersion =  27

Issue reproduced in following emulators : Pixel_2 (oreo 8.0), Nexus_10 (oreo 8.0)

[image]

Comment: when you create your device you add system image api level 26 or 27? It can be relevant - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69168442

Comment: I created emulator using API 26(Oreo 8.0) system image. Issue only  found in device with API 26(Oreo 8.0).